# remove csv rows based on comparison between two values of two columns each in a separate csv

Tags: python, csv, comparison

i have two csv files like this:

file1:

```
ID,Value
ID_15ab_type1,0
ID_15ab_type2,0
ID_19ac_type1,0
ID_19ac_type2,0
ID_26de_type1,1
ID_26de_type2,1
ID_45fe_type1,2
ID_45fe_type2,0
ID_88da_type1,0
ID_88da_type2,0
ID_45ff_type1,0
ID_45ff_type2,1
```

file2:

```
ID,Label
ID_15ab,0
ID_26de,1
ID_45fe,0
```

I want to keep rows in the first file, only rows that have ID similar to the ones in the second csv ID

the output should look like:

```
ID,Value
ID_15ab_type1,0
ID_15ab_type2,0
ID_26de_type1,1
ID_26de_type2,1
ID_45fe_type1,2
ID_45fe_type2,0
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/25973216#) your python code into your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with pandas by creating a new column (by removing the `_type\d+` suffixes you see and ensuring they are in your second frame.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(...)  # ... is path to file 1
df2 = pd.read_csv(...)  # ... is path to file 2

df1["ref"] = df1.ID.str.replace(r"_type\d+", "")
df = df1[df1.ref.isin(df2.ID)][["ID", "Value"]]
df.to_csv("./file3.csv")
```

Comment: thank you it worked fine!!  PS:the second column for df is Value, just change it and it's OK!